# Recurly customer account experience

Tags: recurly

While trying out to see how the customer account experience works in Recurly, I've been having problems understanding https://docs.recurly.com/v1.0/docs/hosted-account-management.

Could someone help me understand the following:

- The hosted account management page for an account logs anyone in without needing to provide any credentials, how do customers manage/change their passwords?
- How can the account management thing be created by Recurly.JS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**The hosted account management page for an account logs anyone in without needing to provide any credentials, how do customers manage/change their passwords?** 
In short, they don't. This link would be something you would use in your app. Say, for example, you have a link to "My Account" on your app. The user would click on that link, which has the HAM token underneath it, and be taken directly to their account inside of Recurly. A user only needs a password if you're going to be sending them to subdomain.recurly.com and having them login to access their account.

**How can the account management thing be created by Recurly.JS?**
Any time an account is generated, the associated token is created with the account. Once you've subscribed a user, do a GET query for account details and store the token locally, for future querying.